# Is there a way to simplify this javascript code? I want to make my javascript code short and simple

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask if this code can be simplified? My codes looks too long. I wanted to have it more simple and short code but delivers the same result. Sorry for asking dumb question. Thank you so much.

```
    // select element by id
var ctaRedWine = document.getElementById("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine= document.getElementById("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = document.getElementById("cta_whitewine");

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("indicator_1").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("indicator_2").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_3").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "0";
   
}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("indicator_1").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_2").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("indicator_3").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "0";
}

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("indicator_1").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_2").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_3").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: there's the chance to encode those stylings in css rules involving a new css class that you will toggle on demand on the least possible amount of elements. There's no chance to see how it could be better optimized because you didn't include the html of those elements you are fetching from document with getElementById.

Comment: It could be just one css class on one element as long as it's the root of the descendents you are going to style. Plus the css class toggling could be embedded in a single function to be attached to all those elements as the click event handler that will take its decisions based on further parameters like maybe data attributes on the elements where you are going to attach the event listener

Comment: How about leaving out purplewine? Nobody drinks it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap what you need in a convenience function.

```
// select element by id

const $ = (el) => document.getElementById(el)

var ctaRedWine = $("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine= $("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = $("cta_whitewine");

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    $("indicator_1").style.opacity = "1";
    $("indicator_2").style.opacity = "0";
    $("indicator_3").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "1";
    $("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "0";

}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    $("indicator_1").style.opacity = "0";
    $("indicator_2").style.opacity = "1";
    $("indicator_3").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "1";
    $("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "0";
}

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    $("indicator_1").style.opacity = "0";
    $("indicator_2").style.opacity = "0";
    $("indicator_3").style.opacity = "1";
    $("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "0";
    $("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Or, taking it further:

```
// select element by id

const $ = (el) => document.getElementById(el)
const $opacity = (el, opacity) => document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = opacity

var ctaRedWine = $("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine= $("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = $("cta_whitewine");

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    $opacity("indicator_1", "1");
    $opacity("indicator_2", "0");
    $opacity("indicator_3", "0");
    $opacity("hero_redwine", "1");
    $opacity("hero_purplewine", "0");
    $opacity("hero_whitewine", "0");

}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    $opacity("indicator_1", "0");
    $opacity("indicator_2", "1");
    $opacity("indicator_3", "0");
    $opacity("hero_redwine", "0");
    $opacity("hero_purplewine", "1");
    $opacity("hero_whitewine", "0");
}

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    $opacity("indicator_1", "0");
    $opacity("indicator_2", "0");
    $opacity("indicator_3", "1");
    $opacity("hero_redwine", "0");
    $opacity("hero_purplewine", "0");
    $opacity("hero_whitewine", "1");
}
```

I'd agree with the other comments though that this might be better done by applying a CSS style to the parent element and having CSS rules apply the opacity to the children.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're making two things in each function

1. Reset them to default
2. Change opacity of certain items

So my proposition is to make a new function called `resetOpacity` which sets all elements opacity to 0 and use it in each onclick

```js
// select element by id
var ctaRedWine = document.getElementById("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine= document.getElementById("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = document.getElementById("cta_whitewine");

var resetOpacity = function () {
    document.getElementById("indicator_1").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_2").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("indicator_3").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "0";
}

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    document.getElementById("indicator_1").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_redwine").style.opacity = "1";
}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    document.getElementById("indicator_2").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_purplewine").style.opacity = "1";
  }

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    document.getElementById("indicator_3").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("hero_whitewine").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

and then you can abstract `document.getElementById...` to single function

```js
// select element by id
var ctaRedWine = document.getElementById("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine= document.getElementById("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = document.getElementById("cta_whitewine");

var setOpacity = function (elementId, opacity) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.opacity = opacity;
}

var resetOpacity = function () {
    setOpacity("indicator_1", "0");
    setOpacity("indicator_2", "0");
    setOpacity("indicator_3", "0");
    setOpacity("hero_redwine", "0");
    setOpacity("hero_purplewine", "0");
    setOpacity("hero_whitewine", "0");
}

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    setOpacity("indicator_1", "1");
    setOpacity("hero_redwine", "1");
}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    setOpacity("indicator_2", "1");
    setOpacity("hero_purplewine", "1");
  }

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    resetOpacity();
    setOpacity("indicator_3", "1");
    setOpacity("hero_whitewine", "1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly had done it using for loops and objects.

Then if you need to add a section to hide or show to your document, you just need to add an object to the array.

And if a new color is added, you can handle this by adding a new key to all the objects.

```js
// select element by id
var ctaRedWine = document.getElementById("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine = document.getElementById("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = document.getElementById("cta_whitewine");

const objects = [
  {id: "indicator_1",red: 1,purple: 0,white: 0},
  {id: "indicator_2",red: 0,purple: 1,white: 0},
  {id: "indicator_3",red: 0,purple: 0,white: 1},
  {id: "hero_redwine",red: 1,purple: 0,white: 0},
  {id: "hero_purplewine",red: 0,purple: 1,white: 0},
  {id: "hero_whitewine",red: 0,purple: 0,white: 1}
]

const setOpacity = (key) => {
    objects.forEach(obj => document.getElementById(obj.id).style.opacity = obj[key])
}

ctaRedWine.onclick = () => setOpacity("red")
ctaPurpleWine.onclick = () => setOpacity("purple")
ctaWhiteWine.onclick = () => setOpacity("white")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want this particular code to be shorter, you could have a single setter which knows what to set already and expects the opacity values only:

```
var ctaRedWine = document.getElementById("cta_redwine");
var ctaPurpleWine = document.getElementById("cta_purplewine");
var ctaWhiteWine = document.getElementById("cta_whitewine");

var elementList=["indicator_1","indicator_2","indicator_3",
                 "hero_redwine","hero_purplewine","hero_whitewine"];
function setOpacities() {
  for(var i=0;i<elementList.length;i++)
    document.getElementById(elementList[i]).style.opacity=arguments[i];
}

ctaRedWine.onclick = function() {
    setOpacities(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

ctaPurpleWine.onclick = function() {
    setOpacities(0,1,0,0,1,0);
}

ctaWhiteWine.onclick = function() {
    setOpacities(0,0,1,0,0,1);
}
```

The actual drawback is that if you want to modify anything in it, following the decoupled identifier-value pairs needs eyeballing and it's easy to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define an array upfront that contains all the info needed to use a simple for loop.

```
const wines = [
  { wine: "red"   , indicator: 1 },
  { wine: "purple", indicator: 2 },
  { wine: "white" , indicator: 3 },
];

for (const {wine, indicator} of wines) {
  document.getElementById(`cta_${wine}wine`).onclick = function () {
    for (const {wine, indicator} of wines) {
      document.getElementById(`indicator_${indicator}`).style.opacity = "0";
      document.getElementById(`hero_${wine}wine`).style.opacity = "0";
    }
    document.getElementById(`indicator_${indicator}`).style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById(`hero_${wine}wine`).style.opacity = "1";
  };
}
```

However, like also mentioned in the comments, using element classes with the associated CSS might be a better solution.